# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in

Tags: php

O meu arquivo está apresentando erro na linha em destaque com o seguinte

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\teste\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 261.

Ainda sou iniciante em php e estou apanhando com isso, podem me ajudar? Codigo abaixo:

```
@param  array|string  $envs

@return string

public function detectEnvironment($envs)
{
   $args = isset($_SERVER['argv']) ? $_SERVER['argv'] : null;
   return $this['env'] = (new EnvironmentDetector())->detect($envs, $args);
}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do php vc usa?

Comment: Estou usando a 5.5